# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in react

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd, package.json, npm-start

I am trying to start a project from gitlab and when I run `npm start` I get this error:

> ```
> tse-front@0.1.0 start
> npm run redirect:env-dev react-scripts start
>
> tse-front@0.1.0 redirect:env-dev
> ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./envs/.env.dev "react-scripts" "start"
>
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

I reinstalled and cleared cache of my node.js but it didn't worked.
I think the issue is here:

```json
"redirect:env-dev": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./envs/.env.dev",
```

---

**Edit:** I have also tried encasing the paths in JSON escaped double quotes, however that didn't work either:

```json
"redirect:env-dev": "\"./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd\" -f \"./envs/.env.dev\""
                     ^^                           ^^    ^^               ^^
```

Comment: The `cmd` tag implies the use of cmd.exe of Microsoft Windows. The path separator character on Windows is a REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just cleaned my node.js cache and then reinstalled it.
The problem was solved.